# How to run a test program with compile executable? C++ / Flex / Bison

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I am working on a project where I am developing a compiler with flex and bison. I have created an executable file, "compile", using this makefile code.

```
compile: scanner.o listing.o
    g++ -o compile scanner.o listing.o
    
scanner.o: scanner.c listing.h tokens.h
    g++ -c scanner.c

scanner.c: scanner.l
    flex scanner.l
    mv lex.yy.c scanner.c

listing.o: listing.cc listing.h
    g++ -c listing.cc
```

In this same directory where the "compile" executable is, I have code written in the custom language I've created in a file called test.txt

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get "compile" to compile with the test.txt and produce output. Can someone help?

I've tried many different solutions. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what are you trying to do. Does the current code work and you want to add some kind of test target? What are the solutions you've tried? How they didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not invoke the `bison` in your `Makefile`. Your `Makefile` should look like this:

```
compiler.tab.c compiler.tab.h: compiler.y
    bison -t -v -d compiler.y

compiler.yy.c: compiler.l compiler.tab.h
    flex compiler.l

compiler: listing.cc listing.h lex.yy.c compiler.tab.c compiler.tab.h
    gcc -o compiler listing.cc compiler.tab.c compiler.yy.c
```

After that you can invoke your compiler like:

```
cat test.txt | ./compiler
```

because auto-generated `main` for `bison` reads input from `stdin`.